# Why still make conditional GET (304) with with expires header

Tags: html, performance-testing, browser-cache, cache-control, web-performance

I'm learning about web performance.

And as I know, when make request to require a resource with header: "expires" or "cache-control" that still valid, the browser'll not make a conditional GET to ask server if a resource has been modified.

So, why the browser alway make conditional GET when i make this request: https://www.debian.org/Pics/debian.png

[screeshot request information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0a2n.png)

Comment: The server response is 304, so no content has been send to the client since the client already has the content/data.

Comment: Yes, but the client always make a request to ask server if resource has been modified? Right? Althought Cache-Control:max-age=604800 is defined in respone header?

Comment: It depends on how you use the URL. If you enter it in your browser and load the URL or press F5, it will send a request because as requested by the user. If you use the URL in a HTML page as an image source, it will check in the local cache first (as seen in the network monitor).

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the request headers: "Cache-Control: max-age=0".

When refreshing an URL, your browser always adds this header to make sure it's "refreshed". If you want to see your real browser's behavior, try navigating to another url then click the back button, Chrome should get the image from its cache.

I've just tried, it does!

Comment: Thank you, I see the request headers. I just wondering that why browser add this "Cache-Control: max-age=0" to make sure it's refresded?
And I did the same as you said, but when i click back button, the browser just re dowload resorce?

Comment: [screenshot here]
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/10KirowED1MIk5qpuk2-Mns3jC773iIz8/view?usp=sharing)
[and here's screenshot of detail timing of request]
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NsIlYADYHmBX2_OmsP5iX0LahSnscLDO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: When you see "Provisional headers are shown" in the Request headers, you're in fact seeing the old saved Response headers and the 200 response code. Check on this view: https://imgur.com/86nFXbS and you should see "from disk cache".

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much